# NullPointerException ao tentar adicionar um JButton em um JLabel de outra classe

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jlabel

Tenho uma classe chamada **Tela**, nessa classe eu crio o meu JFrame e adiciono um JLabel para usar como background, nesse JLabel eu adiciono um botão, no final, essa classe cria esta tela:
[image: Tela inicial do meu jogo]

O problema está ocorrendo na próxima classe, esta classe é chamada após ser pressionado o botão "iniciar jogo", esse botão chama a classe **Menu**, na classe **Menu** eu estou extendendo a classe **Tela** que é quem criou a tela inicial, o problema é que estou tentando usar o JLabel da classe **Tela** para adicionar um novo botão, mas por algum motivo parece que esse JLabel nunca foi instanciada, pois retorna *java.lang.NullPointerException* ao tentar adicionar esse JButton ao JLabel extendido da classe Tela...

Classe Tela:

```
package br.paulo.Game.Tela;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Tela extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ImageIcon image, iconeTitulo; //iconeButtonStartGame;
private JButton btnStartGame, createButton;
protected JLabel bakcgorundLabel;

private Menu menu;

public void initComponents() {
    
    System.out.println("Iniciando componentes...");
    
    Frame();
    
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void Frame() {
    
    this.setTitle("Football Coach Simulator");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocation(-8, 0);
    
    try {
        this.iconeTitulo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/paulo/Game/Tela/resources/imagens/neymaricon.jpg"));
        this.setIconImage(iconeTitulo.getImage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    System.out.println("JFrame criado...");
    
    try {
        this.image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/paulo/Game/Tela/resources/imagens/neymarbg.jpg"));
        setBackground(this.image);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Background setado...");
    
    buttonStartGame();
    System.out.println("Botão start criado...");
}

private void setBackground(ImageIcon image) {
    this.bakcgorundLabel = new JLabel(image);
    this.add(bakcgorundLabel);
}
private void buttonStartGame() {
    this.btnStartGame = new JButton("Iniciar Jogo");
    this.btnStartGame.setBounds(1920 / 2 - 244, 1080 / 2 + 200, 488, 50);
    this.bakcgorundLabel.add(this.btnStartGame);
    
    /*try {
        this.iconeButtonStartGame = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/paulo/Game/Tela/resources/imagens/neymargificonbuttonstartgame.gif"));
        this.btnStartGame.setIcon(iconeButtonStartGame);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }*/
    
    this.btnStartGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            Tela.this.btnStartGame.setVisible(false);
            Tela.this.menu = new Menu();
            menu.Menu();
        }  
    }); 
}
public JButton CreateButton(int posX, int posY, int tamX, int tamY, String name) {
    this.createButton = new JButton(name);
    this.createButton.setBounds(posX, posY, tamX, tamY);
    this.bakcgorundLabel.add(this.createButton);
    this.setVisible(true);
    return this.createButton;
}
}
```

Classe Menu:

```
public class Menu extends Tela {
    
    JButton btnLeft, btnRight;
    JLabel lblEscudo;
    
    public void Menu() {
        btnLeft = CreateButton(20,20,100,100, "aaaa");
    }
}
```

O NullPointerException acontece nesse trecho:

```
this.bakcgorundLabel.add(this.createButton);
```

No caso, eu estou tentando adicionar o botão **createButton** ao label **backgroundLabel**...

Comment: Por favor reduza o código a um [mcve].

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138357/discussion-on-question-by-paulo-ricardo-nullpointerexception-ao-tentar-adicionar)